# Can not replace the field in VerticalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry

I am using following code

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){

     public void run(){
         // your code here
         XmlDataManager xml=new XmlDataManager();
         BitmapField f=xml.getImageFromUrl("http://wiztech.pk/ali/event/"+catg);
         // main1.replace(loading, f);
         // this.setTitle(f);
     }
});
```

To replace the field in  `VerticalFieldManager`, but it throws exception, can any one help please what us wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing i can think of is either `f` is `null`. which means `getImageFromUrl` is not returning a BitmapField. Or `loading` has already been added to another field manager